# Not able to interact with linked divs in firefox/IE

Tags: css, firefox

Apologies if this is a really simple matter. Amateur trying to make a site for an event at work.

I can't get the following page to function as intended in firefox or IE. http://pharmacology.ahc.umn.edu/~ad%5czhan0718/2017-retreat/

The boxes at the bottom of the page are not clickable despite functioning in chrome/safari. I'm not really sure where to start with troubleshooting, so I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'd suggest you see if you can narrow down where the problem is, and make a small reproducable example. Most users will skip over your question and never open your link.

Comment: Probably because a link may only contain inline elements in XHTML. Check out https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpharmacology.ahc.umn.edu%2F~ad%255czhan0718%2F2017-retreat%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Instead of putting the <div> inside an <a> you should make the div itself clickable.

Comment: You should create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Links to live sites are not as efficient, because 1) they contain much code that is irrelevant to the question, 2) if you are currently working on the site, we're looking at a moving target: it may change at any time, and 3) not everybody is going to click on a unknown link just like that.